# UITouchUpInside not calling delegate method

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I have a class MYView(subclass of UIView) and I am adding MyView to My current ViewController as a subView. MyView has a button which calls a delegate method if TouchUpInsideEvent is fired. My problem is when I tap on button the control goes to delegate method but if I fire TouchUpinsideEvent prgramaticaaly it does not call the delegate method.Here is my code:

MyView.h

```
@protocol MyViewDelegate;
@interface MyView : UIView
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<MyViewDelegate> delegate;

@protocol MyViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)selctedOption:(MyView *)slideView withOption:(UILabel *)option withIndex:   (NSInteger *)labelIndex;

@end
```

MyView.m

```
toggleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[toggleButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


//adding target works fine it goes to the finishedDraggingVertical:withEvent method and from there I am calling the delegate method

[toggleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(finishedDraggingVertical:withEvent:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

toggleButton.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, height);

toggleButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:1.1 blue:0.3 alpha:0.2];
[toggleButton.layer setBorderWidth:10.0];
[toggleButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
toggleButton.layer.cornerRadius=10.0;



[self addSubview:toggleButton];
 **//But If I fire the event programatically this doesn't work it goes to finishedDraggingVertical:withEvent but from there it does not go to the delegate method.**
 [toggleButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

MyViewController.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController  <MyViewDelegate>
```

MyViewController.m

//Here I am adding myView and implementing the delegate method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 MyView *myiew1=[[MyView alloc]init];
 myiew1.delegate=self;

[self.view addSubview:slideView1];
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the delegate?

Comment: In my view controller

Comment: Can you show the full protocol declaration for MyViewDelegate and where are you trying to call the delegate?

Comment: Isn't it `[self.view addSubview:myView1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening probably because you are setting the delegate after you have called:

```
 [toggleButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I'm assuming you are adding the toggleButton in the `init` or `initWithFrame` method of your view and the above line of code is also inside the same.

If you print out the `delegate` object just before the delegate method call inside `finishedDraggingVertical:withEvent`, you'll probably get `Nil`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a workaround, but did you try the accepted answer for the below question:

[UIControl: sendActionsForControlEvents omits UIEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382816/uicontrol-sendactionsforcontrolevents-omits-uievent)

Also, check that the actions that you retrieve with `[self actionsForTarget:target forControlEvent:controlEvent]` are consistent with the ones you set earlier in your code. If not, then something is amiss.