# sendActionsForControlEvents doesn't work in Unit Test

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

I wanna trigger testButton's TouchUpInside event in `Unit Test code`, but it seems not working.

```
- (void)testAction {
    UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
   [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleButtonEvent:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [testButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Just do not know how to fix this bug.

Comment: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/ui-testing-in-xcode-7-part-1-ui-testing-gotchas/

Comment: @SachinVas I did unit test, not UI Unit Test.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382816/uicontrol-sendactionsforcontrolevents-omits-uievent without the event this method will never be triggered.